# How to get tilde and plus working with the eshell's directory stack

Tags: eshell, directories

In zsh, when one creates a directory stack with `pushd`, one is able to reference directories in the stack using a tilde followed by the numerical index of the respective directory in the stack.  One can also rotate the stack by calling `pushd` with a plus followed by the same kind of numerical index.

Here is a series of commands which illustrates how this works:

```
> cd /tmp
> dirs -v
0       /tmp
> pushd /home
> dirs -v
0       /home
1       /tmp
> pushd /var/tmp
> dirs -v
0       /var/tmp
1       /home
2       /tmp
> touch foo
> pushd +2
> dirs -v
0       /tmp
1       /var/tmp
2       /home
> mv ~1/foo .
> ls
foo
> pwd
/tmp
```

Is there any way to get the same features in eshell?

Comment: It looks like there is a ```eshell-pushd-dextract``` variable which, ``"If non-nil, make "pushd +n" pop the nth dir to the stack top."`` However, when I set it to ```t``` and then try ```pushd +2``` eshell reports an error: ``"popd: bad arg '2'"``, which is strange because I used pushd, not popd.